# Invoke method just before session expires

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

My webapp has users who login. There is a timeout. Before the session expires, I would like to execute a method to cleanup some locks.

I've implemented a `sessionListener` but once I reach `public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event)` the session is already gone and I need some data from it, so I would like to execute a method (which needs the session alive and be able to access `FacesConfig.getCurrentInstance()`) before the session is actually expired.

How can I do that? Any ideas? This is my Session Listener:

```
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySessionListener.class);

    public MySessionListener() {

    }

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        log.debug("Current Session created : "
              + event.getSession().getId()+ " at "+ new Date());
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // get the destroying session...

        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        prepareLogoutInfoAndLogoutActiveUser(session);

        log.debug("Current Session destroyed :"
              + session.getId()+ " Logging out user...");

        /*
         * nobody can reach user data after this point because 
         * session is invalidated already.
         * So, get the user data from session and save its 
         * logout information before losing it.
         * User's redirection to the timeout page will be 
         * handled by the SessionTimeoutFilter.
         */

         // Only if needed
    }

    /**
     * Clean your logout operations.
     */
    public void prepareLogoutInfoAndLogoutActiveUser(HttpSession httpSession) {
        UserBean user = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "#{user}", UserBean.class);
        LockBean lock = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "#{lock}", LockBean.class);
        lock.unlock(user.getUsername());
        log.info("Unlocked examination for user: "+user.getUsername());
    }
}
```

But I'm getting `NullPointerException` at `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()` because either `getCurrentInstance` is null or `getApplication` returns null

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can achieve that by implementing a HttpSessionBindingListener you need to register a session which holds a lock by calling `registerSession` (the string "sessionBindingListener" may not be changed). The container will callback the `valueUnbound()` method after the session timed out and **before** the session is destroyed.

```
public class ObjectLock implements Serializable,HttpSessionBindingListener {
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        log.info("valueBound:" + event.getName() + " session:" + event.getSession().getId() );

    }

    public void registerSession() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put( "sessionBindingListener", this  );
        log.info( "registered sessionBindingListener"  );
    }

    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        log.info("valueUnBound:" + event.getName() + " session:" + event.getSession().getId() );
               // add you unlock code here:
        clearLocksForSession( event.getSession().getId() );
    }
}
```

Comment: I put it under `UserBean` class, which knows `LockBean`. I had this already implemented there from a previous question answered by...BalusC :D, so I just needed to add the `lock.unlock` line and it worked. Thanks both of you.

Comment: Implementing `HttpSessionBindingListener` is indeed better. You only need to ensure that `registerSession()` is called during a JSF request (however, that method is useless if `ObjectLock` is already a session scoped managed bean.

Comment: If you have a SessionBean, you don't even need to register another listener and access the SessionMap. Since your Bean is already added to the SessionMap, you can just let it implement HttpSessionBindingListener and valueUnbound will be called on the SessionBean directly (because it is bound and unbound by the Framework)

Comment: Is this really work? 
Documentation says "For session that are invalidated or expire, notifications are sent after the session has been invalidated or expired."(https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29)

Answer (score 5):

One more elegant solution:

Just add a `@PreDestroy` Annotation to a Session-Bean! If the Session is going to be destroyed, it will call PreDestroy on all SessionBeans beforehand, there you can logout and everything!

Although this doesn't currently work with many ApplicationServers, seems to be an unclear segment of the JSF Specification. So going with the accepted answer (HttpSessionBindingListener) will be necessary, until @PreDestroy will work as intended on all servers.