# Session timeout Logging in Spring AOP

Tags: java, log4j, session-timeout

I have a requirement to capture Logs for Session Time out using Spring AOP / Log4j. Can any one please provide some idea on it

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean HTTP sessions. You probably need an HttpSessionListener.
Have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943368/invoke-method-just-before-session-expires) question.