# How do I run a method in the session event Onclose/onDestroy?

Tags: java, jsp, session-state

I working with JSP.
I need run a method in ever session closing, i.e., whenever the browser is closed.
how do I make this?

Comment: post you code what you have tried?

Comment: @HagaHood try see this solution for help, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3943485/5593725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server-side you can register an HttpSessionListener:

```
package com.example
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Session created");
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Session destroyed");
    }
}
```

To register you can either add @WebListener annotation to the listner's class or add the listener to web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.MySessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The listener won't be called in the moment when the browser is closed it will be called when the session is timed out.

Comment: it is tihs need tnks

Answer (score 0):

You have to detect the browser close event in javascript.see [Trying to detect browser close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event) to detect browser close event

Send ajax call to serverside which will invalidate the session