# How to log the time in a J2EE application from the session-timeout configuration specified in the web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, session, jakarta-ee, web.xml

> I have this Spring application where I have configured the login and logout function to have an advice which logs their time of execution. But I don't know how to log the time when there is session timeout. I am using Apache Tomcat 7 web server and have configured the session timeout in the web.xml file of my web project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer the link hope it will provide you the details you need [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943368/invoke-method-just-before-session-expires)

Comment: Thanks Rishal, it seems worth a try.

Comment: Welcome @suchit ,upvote if it resolves your requirement.

Comment: Sure will do, but I am off work, definitely by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by implementing a [javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

The [HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed-javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent-) will be invoked when the session expires.

If you annotate your implementation class with [@javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) then Tomcat 7 will install and execute it for you as needed.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I am a newbie to Spring, kept a separate class to implement the HttpSessionListener. Still figuring it out how to weave the same into the application so the overloaded sessionDestroyed method will be called during session expiration.

Comment: Use an @WebListener as noted

Comment: I configured it in the web.xml inside listener tag and it worked perfectly. Thanks Steve.