# Is there a way to log httpsession when it times out?

Tags: httpsession

When httpsession times out, is there a way to log something like "Httpsession with JessionId :'blabla' time out"?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using `HttpSessionBindingListener`. An answer similar to what you need was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943368/invoke-method-just-before-session-expires)

Basically you can add your log by overriding the `valueUnbound` method.